# Creating a class in python using a string as the class name

Tags: python

I have been looking for this for quite sometime and also looked at previously asked questions like:

[how to dynamically create an instance of a class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451779/how-to-dynamically-create-an-instance-of-a-class-in-python)

[Does python have an equivalent to Java Class.forName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname)

[Can you use a string to instantiate a class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553784/can-you-use-a-string-to-instantiate-a-class-in-python)

And also many more, in some of them they are importing the class or using the name of the class somehow in definition.

Edit:

I need to take a list as input and create classes with strings in the list as their name.

```
store_list = {'store1', 'storeabc', 'store234'}
```

Now i can do,

```
store1 = type(store_list[0], (models.Model,), attrs)
storeabc = type(store_list[1], (models.Model,), attrs)
store234 = type(store_list[2], (models.Model), attrs)
```

But i still have to use the names of the class in some way in the code, i have no way of knowing what the list will be, and i want the classes to be created with name taken from the list.

Comment: Do you want to create an object from a class or do you want to create the class itself dynamically? If the later have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555844/dynamically-creating-a-class-from-file-in-python)?

Comment: We need [MCVE] - sample input and expected output.

Comment: Added a bit more information about what i want to do.

Comment: *“But i still have to use the names of the class in some way in the code”* – for example..?

Comment: How can you "use the names of the class ... in the code" when you have "no way of knowing what the names will be" ?

Comment: Yes exactly i can't use the name of the class, for example to create a class using type i still have to use the name of the class, which is what most people have suggested in other answers.

I want a way to create the class without using the name of the class in the code. I want the name to be the string taken from the list.

Comment: I still don’t know what you would need the class name inside the code for. Please show an actual example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the classes you're dynamically creating into a dictionary, mapping class names to classes. This way you can use such a dictionary to access your classes by name later in your code, e.g. to create instances.
For example:

```
store_list = {'store1', 'storeabc', 'store234'}
name2class = {}
for name in store_list:
    name2class[name] = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)
. . .
my_instance = name2class[name](...)
```