# How to get the name of a class from a user and then create a class with that same name

Tags: python, string, class, user-interface, input

I am more oriented into computers programming by themselves by taking information from a user, but I have a curiosity about how to take the name of the class from a user and then create a class with that same name.

For instance,

```
name_of_class = input('What is the name of the class?')
```

and then create a class with that name

Hope you understand my question,
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I don't think it exactly what you wanted, but it seems relatively similar to your question, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported-module

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10555930/5480640, use the `type` method.

```py
name_of_class = input('What is the name of the class?')
ClassFromInput = type(name_of_class, (object,), {})
```