# Inheritance for dynamically generated classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes, radix

Contiuing from this post: [Dynamically creating a class from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555844/dynamically-creating-a-class-from-file), `type(name, bases, dict)` can be used to dynamically create a class with name `name`, with base classes `bases`, and attributes `dict`.

I have classes such as:

```
class City:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 0
class Building:
   def __init__(self):
       self.number = 100
```

I want to create a new class from a string (for ex. "School"), which inherits from the above classes. I have done:

```
School = type("School", (City, Building), {"school_name": "abc"}
s = School()
```

`hasattr(s, "school_name")` gives `True`. However, `hasattr(s, "name")` gives `False`.

How can I make sure that:

1. My dynamically generated class `School` inherits the attributes of its base class(es)?
2. How can I add additional attributes to the class `School` after already creating the class `School = type("School", (Building, Home), {"school_name": "abc"}`? (Suppose I want to add two new attributes (`address`, `pincode`) to the class later on in my script - can I do that?)

Comment: You provide an example of `City` and `Building` but your new type uses `Building` and `Home`...  where's that come from?

Comment: Both `City.__init__` and `Building.__init__` should be calling `super().__init__`. Neither actually defines any *attributes*, though. Even `City().name` would raise an exception.

Comment: Put another way, this has little to do with calling `type` explicitly versus using `class School(Building, Home): ...` instead. (Your call to `type` defines a *class* attribute named `school_name` when `School` is defined.)

Comment: You rarely want to defined classes like this, anyway.

Comment: You can add attributes by defining them in the `dict` dictionary argument. i.e. each key being a function name and the cooresponding value a function `def`.

Comment: On a side note... it's also not the best use of OOP and inheritance anyway... a "School" should have zero or one city's or building's - it is *not* a mix of city/building. eg: a School should have city/building as attributes - not inherit from them.

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on "is-a" and "has-a" principles for OOP

Comment: This is a toy example (StackOverflow recommends giving working snippets of reproducible code, hence a toy example given). The actual class names are different in my actual usecase. I just want to understand how to do the implementation.

Comment: You did a mistake... your code works perfectly:  try with `hasattr(s, "school_name")`

Comment: I want the inherited attributes to be giving `True` as well.

Comment: @AsmitaPoddar okay... maybe it's a toy example... you just don't use inheritance like this is all I'm trying to say

Comment: you should add in the dictionary also the `__init__` which call `super`

Comment: How should I add `__init__` in the dictionary?

Comment: The problem here isn't really that the class is created dynamically, and you would encounter the same problem if you defined your classes this way using a regular class definition statement. it's that your classes are not designed for cooperative multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

City’s **init** method gets override by Building’s **init** method
try

```
hasattr(s, ‘number’)
```

and it should return True.

Define your class as

```
class City:
    name = 0
 
class Building:
    number = 100
```

This way attributes can be inherited.

For the second question, not sure about what you are asking for, but try

```
School.address = ‘foo’
School.pincode = ‘bar’
```

Comment: class attributes != instance attributes

Comment: @cards Thanks for pointing out this. I put all instance attributes to class attributes, which may solve OP’s problem, but be aware it could lead to undesired behavior, i.e. instance initiated before adding/changing class attributes may or may not have that new attributes.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a class dynamically you can also pass methods, "constructor" `__init__` included.

For a class with single parent:

```
# methods & attrs
d = {"school_name": 'abc',
     '__init__': lambda self, *args, **kwargs:
        super(type(self), self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)}

# dynamic class
School = type("School", (City,), d)

# instance
s = School()

print(hasattr(s, 'name'))
#True
print(s.school_name)
#abc
```

For a class with two parents:

```
d = {"school_name": 'abc',
     '__init__': lambda self, *args, **kwargs:
        (City.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs),
        Building.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs))[0]
    }

School = type("School", (City, Building), d)
s = School()

print(hasattr(s, 'name'))
#True
print(hasattr(s, 'number'))
#True
```

The `__init__` is called explicitly for each parent. For more complex stuffs I recommend to write a classical function instead of `lambda`s.

For a class with two parents, base class-free version:

```
d = {"school_name": 'abc',
     '__init__': lambda self, *args, **kwargs:
     [cls.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) for cls in type(self).__bases__][0]
    }
```

**NOTE** if dealing with multiple inheritance where parents classes have different signatures (so the parameters of `__init__`) it could be a big mess if don't pay attention to `*args` & `**kwargs`!

Comment: this would really be a lot clearner if you stopped trying to use a lambda expression to define `__init__`, which is just clumsy. `lambda` expressions are best for pure functions that are meant to return a value, `__init__` is usually exclusively for side-effects.

Comment: also, this is just not how you should be doing the cooperative multiple inheritance, `super(type(self), self)` is a red flag

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga [1] about the lambda: yes, I also mentioned it in my answer... also because functions can be quite complicated. The `___init__` lambda returns a value, `None`. [2]  could you tell more about the "red flag"? I am curiuous... The doc says that _"The two argument form"_ for calls  outside methods as in these cases